# Eigenvalues of $-\Delta u -u\ln u=\lambda u$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

$\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $R^n$
$$
-\Delta u -u\ln u=\lambda u   \\
u|_{\partial\Omega}=0
$$

What  should I read about this eigenvalue question ?  I mean some reference or book.I want to answer this eigenvalue question  as my homework.

At the beginning, I want to use the fix point theory, but if let $Lu=\frac{-\Delta u -u\ln u}{\lambda}$, I don't know what the  $L$ maps suitable space (for example $H_0^2(\Omega)$) to. In fact ,about this question I have asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668567/if-u-in-l2u-and-u0-how-to-show-u-ln-u-in-l2u).

Today I read a connected [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391034/the-solution-to-the-equation-delta-u-lambda-log-uu), but I am unfamiliar with the energy method and don't understand the answer of it. If this is a suitable way for my question, I should read which chapters of Evans' PDE or other books?

I really don't know whether suitable my question is .I just a beginner of PDE. If there are any doubt , please tell me .thanks.

Comment: Is this a proper problem? The PDE is not linear, so there will be no eigenspaces or resolvent operators. In what sense do you speak of eigenvalues?

Comment: @LutzL  Why it will be no eigenspaces?

Comment: Because the equation is not linear. If $u$ is a solution, in general multiples $c·u$, $c\in \Bbb R$ const., will not be solutions. Not to speak of linear combinations.